# Reading and checking strings from user input

Tags: java, string, input, user-input

I have this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = input.nextLine();

    if(answer == "yes"){
        System.out.println("Yea I programmed this right!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Awww :(");
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run it and type *yes*, it should be saying

**"Yea I programmed this right!"**

but it says

"**Awww :(**"

Comment: A `String` is an object, not a primitive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're comparing strings incorrectly. You must use the `equals()` method, like this:

```
if (answer.equals("yes"))
```

When you're programming in Java, the operator `==` is generally used for comparing primitive data types (`int`, `double`, etc.). If you use `==` for comparing two object types (like strings), you're comparing them for *identity*, that is, checking if they reference the same object in memory. In your case, what you need is to compare if they're *equal*: if they have the exact same value (a string of characters in this case) even if they're two different objects - and for that you must use the `equals()` method.

**EDIT :**

Even better, for preventing a `NullPointerException`, it's considered a good practice flipping the order of the comparison and writing first the string you're comparing with, like this:

```
if ("yes".equals(answer))
```

The explanation is simple: if for some reason `answer` is `null`, the above comparison will evaluate to `false` (meaning: `answer` is not `"yes"`), whereas the first version of the code would cause a `NullPointerException` when trying to call the `equals()` method on a `null` value.

Comment: +1 for everything here, but you should still flip the order of the comparison to prevent a possible NPE.  (Details in my answer.)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(answer == "yes"){
```

should be

```
if("yes".equals(answer)){
```

(`==` is not correct for `String` equality, and we handle the case where `answer` is null)

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.equals()` instead of `==`.

In Java, `==` is testing that the 2 Strings are the exact same instance, where "a" != "a".  Instead, you need to test for `"a".equals("a")`.

So replace

```
if(answer == "yes"){
```

with:

```
if("yes".equals(answer)){
```

Note that flipping the order here is intentional, as this can prevent a NullPointerException if `answer` was null - as `"yes".equals(null)` will simply return false, instead of throwing an exception.  (Calling an operation on `null` would throw a NullPointerException, I.E. `null.equals("yes")`.)

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
if(answer.equals("yes")){
    System.out.println("Yea I programmed this right!");
}else{
    System.out.println("Awww :(");
}
```

The `equals()` method compares *this* string (*answer in your example*) to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

It is important to understand that the `equals()` method and the `==` operator perform two different operations. As just mentioned, the `equals()` method compares the characters inside a String object. The `==` operator compares two object references to see whether they refer to the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String answer = input.nextLine();

/*Edit your next line as mine,u'll get the correct ans...*/

if("yes".equals(answer)){ 
    System.out.println("Yea I programmed this right!");
}else{
    System.out.println("Awww :(");
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

or you can try to use "compareTo()" function

```
private static Scanner input;
private static String choice;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    choice = input.nextLine();

    if (choice.compareTo("yes") == 0) {
        System.out.println("Yea I programmed this right!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Awww :(");
    }

}
```